# Easiest way of working with a comma separated list

Tags: c#, regex, string, csv

I'm about to build a solution to where I receive a comma separated list every night. It's a list with around 14000 rows, and I need to go through the list and select some of the values in the list.
The document I receive is built up with around 50 semicolon separated values for every "case". How the document is structured:

"";"2010-10-17";"";"";"";Period-Last24h";"Problem is that the customer cant find....";
and so on, with 43 more semicolon statements. And every "case" ends with the value "Total 515";

What I need to do is go through all these "cases" and withdraw some of the values in the "cases". The "cases" is always built up in the same order and I know that it's always the 3, 15 and 45'th semicolon value that I need to withdraw.

How can I do this in the easiest way?

Comment: you don't necessarily need a regex for that....

Comment: Ok, what else would you recommend

Answer (score 2):

I think you should decompose this problem into smaller problems.  Here are the steps I'd take:

1. Each semi-colon separated record represents a single object.  C# is an object-oriented language.  Stop thinking in terms of .csv records and start thinking in terms of objects.  Break up the input into semi-colon delimited records.
2. Given a single comma-separated record, the values represent the properties of your object.  Give them meaningful names.
3. Parse a comma-separated record into an object.  When you're done, you'll have a collection of objects that you can deal with.
4. Use C#'s collections and LINQ to filter your list based on those cases that you need to withdraw.  When you're done, you'll have a collection of objects with the desired cases removed.

Don't worry about the "easiest" way.  You need *one* way that works.  Whatever you do, get something working and worry about optimizing it to make it easiest, fastest, smallest, etc. later on.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "rows" are lines and that you read line by line, your main tool should be string.Split:

```
foreach (string line in ... )
{
   string [] parts = line.split (';');
   string part3 = parts[2];
   string part15 = parts[14];
   // etc
}
```

Note that this is a simple approach that will fail if the content of any column can contain ';'

Comment: I second the line by line/string.split() approach. Note that this approach won't work if there are no CR or LF delimiters between lines - the OP didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) twice.

The first time using "Total 515"; as the split string using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx). This will give you an array of cases.

The second time using ";" as the split character using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) on each of the cases. This will give you a data array for each case. As the data is consistent you can extract the 3<sup>rd</sup>, 15<sup>th</sup> and 45<sup>th</sup> elements of this array.

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for an existing csv library. The escaping rules are probably not that easily mapped to regex.

If writing a library myself I'd first parse each line into a list/an array of strings. And then in a second step(probably outside of the csv library itself) convert the stringlist to a strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but slow approach would be reading single characters from the input (`StringReader` class, for example). Write a `ReadItem` method that reads a quote, continues to read until the next quote, and then looks for the next character. If it is a newline of semicolon, one item has been read. If it is another quote, add a single quote to the item being read. Otherwise, throw an exception. Then use this method to split up the input data into a series of items, each line stored e.g. in a `string[number of items in a row]`, lines stored in a `List<>`. Then you can use this class to read the CSV data inside another class that decodes the data read into objects that you can get your data out of.